# Full screen popup from iframe (featherlight)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, featherlight.js

This is a very specific problem.
There is a website (I have no access to this site) with a few iframes in it, one of these iframes is linking to a site I have access to.

My iframe should contain a link to another iframe and open it as popup when the link is clicked. This is already working. I use [featherlight.js](https://noelboss.github.io/featherlight/) for this.

The **problem** now is that when I click the link on the site I have no access to, **the popup size is limited to the size of the iframe**.

---

Example for clarification

Code on my site, let's call it `example.com`

```
<a id="popup" href="anotherlink" data-featherlight="iframe">Open popup</a>
<script>
    $("#popup").featherlight();
</script>
```

And the code on the site I have no access to looks like:

```
<iframe src="example.com"></iframe>
```

Comment: I'm not sure but I'd imagine this isn't possible, the browser blocks it, otherwise people using iframe for ads would open huge overlays on every site. I might be wrong though.

Comment: This is not trivial since the css for the popup doesn't exist in the parent page. You either need to be able to make your iframe fill the parent page when you want to display popup or be able to clone the popup html, css etc and append it to the parent. The css could have conflicts with the parent also and your plugin would need modification. Both issues may be blocked by browser security when you try to access parent window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after a quick read: this is not possible as the content of the iframe is not always trusted, this means that the iframe's content could place an identical login box over the legit one and steal all the user's information.

If you really need that popup to be over your site I think the only way to achieve it is to load the content through ajax and inject the thing in a specific `div` in your site.